# Resize image along with the div

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, image-resizing, background-position

I am unable to resize the image that is within the div. The div is working properly, but the image is inside the div remains the same size.

How to grow and shrink the image along with the div?

```
div.column {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto
}

div.fixedratio {
    padding-top: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/4pgtZwz.png');
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-position: center center;
}

.tengah {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


<div class="column">
   <div class="fixedratio">
      <div class="tengah">
           <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/5ocnzd117/icon_player_soccer.png">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffernandes/f05jh0gs/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the background-size:contain CSS property on the image to make it scale with the div as it re-sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could of an example?

Comment: Sure no problem. tengah {
background-size:contain
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css to change the images size like so:

```
.tengah img{
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 }
```

That will change the width of the image to a size percentage relative to the parent container.

Comment: I just used 50% there but you can set it to whatever percentage you need.

Comment: I'm looking at the fiddle and added the exact code above and it's changing the size of the image.